# IOS: UIScrollView not scrolling with Auto layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am using `UIScrollView` with which i want to display user cards entered in our app.I am using a `CustomView` named `SavedCardView` to display card info.The problem I'm having is when i set the width of `SavedCardView` the scrollview stops scrolling otherwise it works perfectly adjusting `SaveCardView` width automatically based on subviews. I am using the following code to add `SavedCardView` to `SavedCardsContentView` which is a subview of `UIScrollView` with its top, bottom, leading & trailing constraints align to scrollview. I have set the height of 'SavedCardsContentView` to 180 pts.

```
//Add the card views
SavedCardView *previousView = nil;
for ( Card *card in _savedCards ) {
    //Load the card view from the xib file
    // Instantiate the nib content without any reference to it.
    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SavedCardView" owner:nil options:nil];

    // Find the view among nib contents (not too hard assuming there is only one view in it).
    SavedCardView *cardView = [nibContents lastObject];

    // Add the user card to saved cardView
    [cardView updateViews:card];

    //Set the translate auto resizing mask to false
    [cardView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    //Add the view to the events container
    [_savedCardsContentView addSubview:cardView];
    //[cardView setSaveCardViewDelegate:self];

    // Set width constraint
    [cardView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:260]];

    //Start adding the remaining constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint;
    if ( !previousView ) {
        //Add the left constraint to the parent view
        leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_savedCardsContentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:20];
    } else {
        //Add the left constraint to the previous view
        leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:20];
    }
    [_savedCardsContentView addConstraint:leftConstraint];

    //Add the top and bottom constraint
    [_savedCardsContentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_savedCardsContentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    [_savedCardsContentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_savedCardsContentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    if ( [card isEqual:[_savedCards lastObject]] ) {
        //Add the trailing constraint to the cards content view
        [_savedCardsContentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_savedCardsContentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cardView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
    }

    previousView = cardView;
}
```

I have no idea why its not woking after setting `SavedCardView` width, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are setting a height for the `SavedCardView`. Once you add the width constraint (unless you have an aspect ratio constraint for it) I'm guessing the `intrinsicContentSize` of the `cardView` is ignored. The UIView docs state: "This intrinsic size must be independent of the content frame, because there’s no way to dynamically communicate a changed width to the layout system based on a changed height, for example." Have you tried implementing `-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize` in the `SavedCardView` implementation? You could hard-code the width there, if it makes sense.

Comment: Hey sorry, forgot to tell how `SavedCardView` is getting it's height. I have set the height of `SavedCardsContentView` to 180 and as `SavedCardView` is aligned to its top and bottom, it's height is 180 also. Have edited my question.